# how can i get the value of this Json objects using android Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

in this link there is weather `JSON` information 
http://api.wunderground.com/api/89ef283108b7ea38/hourly/q/CA/San_Francisco.json

and i am trying to get the values list of this fields 
yday , temp>metric , dewpoint>metric , condition

but within the root class i can not SerializeName more that class attribute to the same SerializeName which is `hourly_forecast` like this

```
public class Hourly_forecast_Children {

    @SerializedName("hourly_forecast")
    public List<DewpointInfo> dinfo;

    @SerializedName("hourly_forecast")
    public List< TemoInfo> tinfo;


    @SerializedName("hourly_forecast")
    public List<WeatherData> winfo;



    @SerializedName("hourly_forecast")
    public List< FCTTIME > finfo;
}
```

and i got this error

```
05-16 21:54:55.334 16529-16529/com.example.tofaa.gsondemo2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tofaa.gsondemo2, PID: 16529
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tofaa.gsondemo2/com.example.tofaa.gsondemo2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.tofaa.gsondemo2.json.Hourly_forecast_Children declares multiple JSON fields named hourly_forecast
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.tofaa.gsondemo2.json.Hourly_forecast_Children declares multiple JSON fields named hourly_forecast
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:878)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:844)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:793)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:765)
at com.example.tofaa.gsondemo2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

so i tried everyone indvisually and it works fine 
what should i do to make them all work together

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same serailized name `"hourly_forecast"` for every variable. So Gson gets confused in parsing `"hours_forecast"` to the correct variable.

Your `Hourly_forecast_Children` class should be some thing like this as per the API.

```
/**
 * version : 0.1
 * termsofService : http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html
 * features : {"hourly":1}
 */

private ResponseEntity response;
/**
 * FCTTIME : {"hour":"17","hour_padded":"17","min":"00","min_unpadded":"0","sec":"0","year":"2016","mon":"5","mon_padded":"05","mon_abbrev":"May","mday":"16","mday_padded":"16","yday":"136","isdst":"1","epoch":"1463443200","pretty":"5:00 PM PDT on May 16, 2016","civil":"5:00 PM","month_name":"May","month_name_abbrev":"May","weekday_name":"Monday","weekday_name_night":"Monday Night","weekday_name_abbrev":"Mon","weekday_name_unlang":"Monday","weekday_name_night_unlang":"Monday Night","ampm":"PM","tz":"","age":"","UTCDATE":""}
 * temp : {"english":"65","metric":"18"}
 * dewpoint : {"english":"53","metric":"12"}
 * condition : Clear
 * icon : clear
 * icon_url : http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif
 * fctcode : 1
 * sky : 9
 * wspd : {"english":"16","metric":"26"}
 * wdir : {"dir":"W","degrees":"278"}
 * wx : Sunny
 * uvi : 3
 * humidity : 64
 * windchill : {"english":"-9999","metric":"-9999"}
 * heatindex : {"english":"-9999","metric":"-9999"}
 * feelslike : {"english":"65","metric":"18"}
 * qpf : {"english":"0.0","metric":"0"}
 * snow : {"english":"0.0","metric":"0"}
 * pop : 0
 * mslp : {"english":"29.9","metric":"1013"}
 */

private List<HourlyForecastEntity> hourly_forecast;

public ResponseEntity getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(ResponseEntity response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public List<HourlyForecastEntity> getHourly_forecast() {
    return hourly_forecast;
}

public void setHourly_forecast(List<HourlyForecastEntity> hourly_forecast) {
    this.hourly_forecast = hourly_forecast;
}

public static class ResponseEntity {
    private String version;
    private String termsofService;
    /**
     * hourly : 1
     */

    private FeaturesEntity features;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getTermsofService() {
        return termsofService;
    }

    public void setTermsofService(String termsofService) {
        this.termsofService = termsofService;
    }

    public FeaturesEntity getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(FeaturesEntity features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

    public static class FeaturesEntity {
        private int hourly;

        public int getHourly() {
            return hourly;
        }

        public void setHourly(int hourly) {
            this.hourly = hourly;
        }
    }
}

public static class HourlyForecastEntity {
    /**
     * hour : 17
     * hour_padded : 17
     * min : 00
     * min_unpadded : 0
     * sec : 0
     * year : 2016
     * mon : 5
     * mon_padded : 05
     * mon_abbrev : May
     * mday : 16
     * mday_padded : 16
     * yday : 136
     * isdst : 1
     * epoch : 1463443200
     * pretty : 5:00 PM PDT on May 16, 2016
     * civil : 5:00 PM
     * month_name : May
     * month_name_abbrev : May
     * weekday_name : Monday
     * weekday_name_night : Monday Night
     * weekday_name_abbrev : Mon
     * weekday_name_unlang : Monday
     * weekday_name_night_unlang : Monday Night
     * ampm : PM
     * tz :
     * age :
     * UTCDATE :
     */

    private FCTTIMEEntity FCTTIME;
    /**
     * english : 65
     * metric : 18
     */

    private TempEntity temp;
    /**
     * english : 53
     * metric : 12
     */

    private DewpointEntity dewpoint;
    private String condition;
    private String icon;
    private String icon_url;
    private String fctcode;
    private String sky;
    /**
     * english : 16
     * metric : 26
     */

    private WspdEntity wspd;
    /**
     * dir : W
     * degrees : 278
     */

    private WdirEntity wdir;
    private String wx;
    private String uvi;
    private String humidity;
    /**
     * english : -9999
     * metric : -9999
     */

    private WindchillEntity windchill;
    /**
     * english : -9999
     * metric : -9999
     */

    private HeatindexEntity heatindex;
    /**
     * english : 65
     * metric : 18
     */

    private FeelslikeEntity feelslike;
    /**
     * english : 0.0
     * metric : 0
     */

    private QpfEntity qpf;
    /**
     * english : 0.0
     * metric : 0
     */

    private SnowEntity snow;
    private String pop;
    /**
     * english : 29.9
     * metric : 1013
     */

    private MslpEntity mslp;

    public FCTTIMEEntity getFCTTIME() {
        return FCTTIME;
    }

    public void setFCTTIME(FCTTIMEEntity FCTTIME) {
        this.FCTTIME = FCTTIME;
    }

    public TempEntity getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(TempEntity temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public DewpointEntity getDewpoint() {
        return dewpoint;
    }

    public void setDewpoint(DewpointEntity dewpoint) {
        this.dewpoint = dewpoint;
    }

    public String getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(String condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getIcon_url() {
        return icon_url;
    }

    public void setIcon_url(String icon_url) {
        this.icon_url = icon_url;
    }

    public String getFctcode() {
        return fctcode;
    }

    public void setFctcode(String fctcode) {
        this.fctcode = fctcode;
    }

    public String getSky() {
        return sky;
    }

    public void setSky(String sky) {
        this.sky = sky;
    }

    public WspdEntity getWspd() {
        return wspd;
    }

    public void setWspd(WspdEntity wspd) {
        this.wspd = wspd;
    }

    public WdirEntity getWdir() {
        return wdir;
    }

    public void setWdir(WdirEntity wdir) {
        this.wdir = wdir;
    }

    public String getWx() {
        return wx;
    }

    public void setWx(String wx) {
        this.wx = wx;
    }

    public String getUvi() {
        return uvi;
    }

    public void setUvi(String uvi) {
        this.uvi = uvi;
    }

    public String getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(String humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    public WindchillEntity getWindchill() {
        return windchill;
    }

    public void setWindchill(WindchillEntity windchill) {
        this.windchill = windchill;
    }

    public HeatindexEntity getHeatindex() {
        return heatindex;
    }

    public void setHeatindex(HeatindexEntity heatindex) {
        this.heatindex = heatindex;
    }

    public FeelslikeEntity getFeelslike() {
        return feelslike;
    }

    public void setFeelslike(FeelslikeEntity feelslike) {
        this.feelslike = feelslike;
    }

    public QpfEntity getQpf() {
        return qpf;
    }

    public void setQpf(QpfEntity qpf) {
        this.qpf = qpf;
    }

    public SnowEntity getSnow() {
        return snow;
    }

    public void setSnow(SnowEntity snow) {
        this.snow = snow;
    }

    public String getPop() {
        return pop;
    }

    public void setPop(String pop) {
        this.pop = pop;
    }

    public MslpEntity getMslp() {
        return mslp;
    }

    public void setMslp(MslpEntity mslp) {
        this.mslp = mslp;
    }

    public static class FCTTIMEEntity {
        private String hour;
        private String hour_padded;
        private String min;
        private String min_unpadded;
        private String sec;
        private String year;
        private String mon;
        private String mon_padded;
        private String mon_abbrev;
        private String mday;
        private String mday_padded;
        private String yday;
        private String isdst;
        private String epoch;
        private String pretty;
        private String civil;
        private String month_name;
        private String month_name_abbrev;
        private String weekday_name;
        private String weekday_name_night;
        private String weekday_name_abbrev;
        private String weekday_name_unlang;
        private String weekday_name_night_unlang;
        private String ampm;
        private String tz;
        private String age;
        private String UTCDATE;

        public String getHour() {
            return hour;
        }

        public void setHour(String hour) {
            this.hour = hour;
        }

        public String getHour_padded() {
            return hour_padded;
        }

        public void setHour_padded(String hour_padded) {
            this.hour_padded = hour_padded;
        }

        public String getMin() {
            return min;
        }

        public void setMin(String min) {
            this.min = min;
        }

        public String getMin_unpadded() {
            return min_unpadded;
        }

        public void setMin_unpadded(String min_unpadded) {
            this.min_unpadded = min_unpadded;
        }

        public String getSec() {
            return sec;
        }

        public void setSec(String sec) {
            this.sec = sec;
        }

        public String getYear() {
            return year;
        }

        public void setYear(String year) {
            this.year = year;
        }

        public String getMon() {
            return mon;
        }

        public void setMon(String mon) {
            this.mon = mon;
        }

        public String getMon_padded() {
            return mon_padded;
        }

        public void setMon_padded(String mon_padded) {
            this.mon_padded = mon_padded;
        }

        public String getMon_abbrev() {
            return mon_abbrev;
        }

        public void setMon_abbrev(String mon_abbrev) {
            this.mon_abbrev = mon_abbrev;
        }

        public String getMday() {
            return mday;
        }

        public void setMday(String mday) {
            this.mday = mday;
        }

        public String getMday_padded() {
            return mday_padded;
        }

        public void setMday_padded(String mday_padded) {
            this.mday_padded = mday_padded;
        }

        public String getYday() {
            return yday;
        }

        public void setYday(String yday) {
            this.yday = yday;
        }

        public String getIsdst() {
            return isdst;
        }

        public void setIsdst(String isdst) {
            this.isdst = isdst;
        }

        public String getEpoch() {
            return epoch;
        }

        public void setEpoch(String epoch) {
            this.epoch = epoch;
        }

        public String getPretty() {
            return pretty;
        }

        public void setPretty(String pretty) {
            this.pretty = pretty;
        }

        public String getCivil() {
            return civil;
        }

        public void setCivil(String civil) {
            this.civil = civil;
        }

        public String getMonth_name() {
            return month_name;
        }

        public void setMonth_name(String month_name) {
            this.month_name = month_name;
        }

        public String getMonth_name_abbrev() {
            return month_name_abbrev;
        }

        public void setMonth_name_abbrev(String month_name_abbrev) {
            this.month_name_abbrev = month_name_abbrev;
        }

        public String getWeekday_name() {
            return weekday_name;
        }

        public void setWeekday_name(String weekday_name) {
            this.weekday_name = weekday_name;
        }

        public String getWeekday_name_night() {
            return weekday_name_night;
        }

        public void setWeekday_name_night(String weekday_name_night) {
            this.weekday_name_night = weekday_name_night;
        }

        public String getWeekday_name_abbrev() {
            return weekday_name_abbrev;
        }

        public void setWeekday_name_abbrev(String weekday_name_abbrev) {
            this.weekday_name_abbrev = weekday_name_abbrev;
        }

        public String getWeekday_name_unlang() {
            return weekday_name_unlang;
        }

        public void setWeekday_name_unlang(String weekday_name_unlang) {
            this.weekday_name_unlang = weekday_name_unlang;
        }

        public String getWeekday_name_night_unlang() {
            return weekday_name_night_unlang;
        }

        public void setWeekday_name_night_unlang(String weekday_name_night_unlang) {
            this.weekday_name_night_unlang = weekday_name_night_unlang;
        }

        public String getAmpm() {
            return ampm;
        }

        public void setAmpm(String ampm) {
            this.ampm = ampm;
        }

        public String getTz() {
            return tz;
        }

        public void setTz(String tz) {
            this.tz = tz;
        }

        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getUTCDATE() {
            return UTCDATE;
        }

        public void setUTCDATE(String UTCDATE) {
            this.UTCDATE = UTCDATE;
        }
    }

    public static class TempEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class DewpointEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class WspdEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class WdirEntity {
        private String dir;
        private String degrees;

        public String getDir() {
            return dir;
        }

        public void setDir(String dir) {
            this.dir = dir;
        }

        public String getDegrees() {
            return degrees;
        }

        public void setDegrees(String degrees) {
            this.degrees = degrees;
        }
    }

    public static class WindchillEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class HeatindexEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class FeelslikeEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class QpfEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class SnowEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }

    public static class MslpEntity {
        private String english;
        private String metric;

        public String getEnglish() {
            return english;
        }

        public void setEnglish(String english) {
            this.english = english;
        }

        public String getMetric() {
            return metric;
        }

        public void setMetric(String metric) {
            this.metric = metric;
        }
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend to use [GSONFormat](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654?pr=) plugin in Android studio to generate the boiler plate code for GSon parsing.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Sha

Comment: it just help to format the code ,, but how can i add values to this attributes ?

Comment: If you are using Gson library to parse the Json, GSon takes care of assigning the values, the only rule is the propery name should have same name as variable or use a `SerializedName` parameter to define the Json tag. GSonFormat will take care of generating the variables with same Name as JSon.